# How can I get the actual grid row height of a grid with RowDefinition Height *

Tags: wpf

```
     <Grid x:Name="SidebarGrid" LayoutUpdated="gridlayoutupdated">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="250" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

The Row sizes to content, but after the content is set, I would like to get the height.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [RowDefinition.ActualHeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.rowdefinition.actualheight) (but note that it is not data-bindable).

Comment: Have an example? I've tried binding `<ScrollViewer Height={Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=RowDefinition}}>` with no luck

Comment: What I did was have the rowDefinition like this `<RowDefinition Name=rowDefinition1"/>` and set the binding with
`<ScollViewer Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=rowDefinition1}"/>`

Comment: Actually, since ActualHeight on row definition isn't a dependency property, I scrapped it and just settled for making a SizeChanged event handler in the xaml code behind. I want to figure out the best MVVM way to do it though.